# How to install MPEG-2 Transport Stream demuxer under gstreamer ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, video, gstreamer

I have ubuntu 16.04 and I would like to inspect video files with gstreamer. I have these gstreamer packages installed:

```
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-alsa/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/xenial,now 3.0.18-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 all [installed]
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3/xenial,now 0.10.32.debian-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-libav/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 all [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 all [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 all [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-dbg/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 all [installed]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-tools/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-x/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-0/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-dev/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I would like to inspect a .ts video file in H264 format.

I give the command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=file:///myvideofile.ts ! videoconvert ! identity silent=false ! fakesink
```

And I get the error message:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstFileSrc\)\ source"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
Missing element: MPEG-2 Transport Stream demuxer
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: No decoder available for type 'video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188'.
Additional debug info:
gsturidecodebin.c(931): unknown_type_cb (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
gsturidecodebin.c(998): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
gstdecodebin2.c(4600): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: MPEG-2 Transport Stream (video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188)

ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

How can I install this missing MPEG-2 decoder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i got more or less the same error message while trying to import a .ts video in [gaupol](https://otsaloma.io/gaupol/) . what i did is going to the synaptic package manager, search for all packages with the keyword "gstreamer", and installed :

- gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
- and gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad

that worked for me